# Differences beteween Threading in Nvidias GPUs and CPUs

Tags: multithreading, cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

I am trying to understand the difference between the threading techniques used by Nividia GPUs and normal (multi threading) CPUs. In particular my two questions are:

- Which part of the system is respondsible for the thread scheduling and according to which aspects are they scheduled?
- Are threads processed synchronously?

Answer (score 1):

CUDA cores and CPU cores are literally a complete different thing - the name is more a marketing thing;

What do you mean with responsible for thread scheduling? Its mostly both Software and Hardware. For instance the pure CPU has little to do with the actual thread scheduling, but provides the necessary functionality to implement a thread-scheduler as a part of the OS. So the scheduling parameter are defined by the software. Hence you should adopt your question to a specific OS.

One thing the CPU provides are the so called hardware-threads. Each hardware-thread allows the "parallel" execution of one software-thread. (Note: With Hyperthreading, the execution is not really parallel more interleaving). The scheduler distributes all running threads on these hardware-threads.

This is basically a [MIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flynn%27s_taxonomy)-System.

The scheduling on graphic-cards are way more complicated. In short:
You have a few thousands CUDA-cores - but in contrast to the CPU you cannot assign a unique application to each of them. The CUDA-cores are organized in groups (so called warps) and all CUDA-cores inside the same group execute the same thread simultaneously.

This is called [SIMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_threads)